# Emacs: print with line numbers

Tags: emacs, printing

Does anyone know how to print with the line numbers of the code in the margin? I can display the line number, cannot have that in the printout. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the line numbers with temporary overlays and convert the buffer to HTML using the [`htmlize`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize) package, after which you can save the HTML and print using `lpr` or a browser.

```
(defun htmlize-with-line-numbers ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let ((n 1))
    (while (not (eobp))
      (htmlize-make-tmp-overlay (point) (point) `(before-string ,(format "%4d " n)))
      (setq n (1+ n))
      (forward-line 1)))
  (switch-to-buffer (htmlize-buffer)))
```

This will require a recent version of `htmlize`.

Comment: If printing from the command line is an option and you don't necessarily need colors, consider `cat -n` instead of htmlize.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the solution on such an old post.  I used `ps-print-buffer` rather than `print-buffer`, since the results are *much* nicer looking. Anyway, for some reason it is not documented in the manual, but if you look at the source for `ps-print.el`, you find the `ps-line-number` variable that you can set to non-nil in order include line numbers.

```
M-x set-variable RET ps-line-number RET t
```

That should set it temporarily so that you can print. You may want to set it permanently in your `init.el`.

You can also print using the `M-x pr-interface` command, which brings up a buffer of all sorts of printing options.

Comment: I was unaware of pr-interface; it works really nicely.

Comment: Thanks very much. I wish I could click the up button more times on this one. It solves a major problem for us.

Answer (score 3):

An easy yet hackish way would of course be to temporarily insert line numbers directly into the buffer

```
C-<
C-M-% ^ RET \,(1+ \#) SPC RET
```

then print it

```
M-x print-buffer
```

and then undo the line numbers again:

```
C-/
C-u C-SPC
```

The result is not very beautiful, but usable. There are three main problems:

- you're making changes to the buffer. In particular, that means the buffer must not be read-only.
- the line numbers are left justified which means you get different indentation depending on the number of digits in the line number.
- your major mode will trip over the line numbers and you'll lose the syntax highlighting. If you're printing on a black-and-white printer that's not a problem though.

You could fix the second point by using a more complicated replacement string:

```
\,(format "%4d " (1+ \#))
```

but then you have to know what is the maximum line number so you can give the right number of digits between `%` and `d`. You could of course just jump to the end of the buffer quickly to check the maximum line number. But more importantly, it's becoming a pain to type all that every time you want to print line numbers.

Comment: Cool — I’ve never used the special codes in the replacement string! I just wanted to clarify where the spaces go in the replacement string (I’ll mark them with bullets for clarity): `\,(1+•\#)•`

Comment: @illya That's right, thanks for the clarification. `\,` interprets the following expression as Lisp code, and `\#` is the replacement counter. So you basically call the function `1+` on the replacement counter and insert the result at the beginning of the line.